# encoding a dictionary value in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

`print ('Description:', repo_dict['description'])` this line is giving me this error.

```
print ('Description:', repo_dict['description'])   File
"C:\python3.6\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
position 33-35: character maps to <undefined>
```

I want to encode this dictionary value and I am using this code in a `for` loop. Is there a way to encode a dictionary's value? And yes, I am pulling this data through API.

Comment: What is stored in `repo_dict`?

Comment: information about GitHub top repositories for python, description is the description about the current repository in the loop being examined.

Comment: OK, can you provide some example data, giving you the error you see?